# Position: sticky for sidebar when parent container has fixed height

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, sticky

I want to have a container that doesn't exceed a certain height, with a 2 column layout: a large main section which sticks at the top while the user scrolls through the items in the sidebar. I tried setting a fixed height and overflow onto the container but this has broken the position: sticky. Is this possible without having lots of space at the bottom, when there's lots of items in the sidebar? I would like for these items to not overflow the height of the container (i.e. the height of the column 1 section).

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

.header,
.footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 120px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px 0;
  max-height:400px;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.col-1 {
 flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.col-inner {
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col-inner {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">Header</header>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class='col-inner'>Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>      
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: don't create multiple accounts to ask the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73159562/8620333 (edit your old question)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Hopefully this helps: I took your code as you listed above and added:

```
.col-2{
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 300px;
}
```

This allowed me to scroll on your col-2 element while maintaining a fixed height.

Comment: That would be great if the purple column 1 section remained sticky at the top :(